# Expected number of random choices required to find all combinations

Tags: probability, combinations

If I have $n$ urns each containing $m$ distinct items, where the the urns are disjoint sets, and I repeatedly draw an item from each urn with replacement to make an $n$-combination, how many such $n$-combinations would I expect to have to make in order to see every one of the $m^n$ possible $n$-combinations?

Comment: What do you mean by disjoint? Do you mean distinct? If so, it would be $m^n$ different possible $n$-combinations. If you kept track of which ones items you took each time, then you could make exactly $m^n$ drawings and be done. If you were pulling randomly, this problem becomes more difficult.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I mean that the urns have no items in common - they are disjoint sets.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe And yes, it is random choice.

Comment: So you have $m$ distinct items in one urn, but these sets of items are the same for both urns?

Comment: @callculus No, the items in the urns are distinct as well as the urns being disjoint. There are $m^n$ combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). The expected number of draws will be:

$$m^nH_{m^n}$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.

Comment: That looks good InterstellarProbe - I was aware of the Coupon Collector's Problem. Have you seen this particular problem in the literature or did you just work out the answer?

Comment: I thought, if each $n$-combination was a "coupon", this would be the Coupon Collector's problem. There was nothing really to work out.

Comment: Great, I'll see if anyone else weighs in and accept your answer if they don't.

Comment: Isn't the idea here that it is equivalent to have simply a set of $m^n$ distinct items, then draw one at a time with replacement until you have seen every one of them -- that is, you don't need the $n$ urns and $m$ items per urn set up -- in which case it is the standard Coupon Collector.

Comment: Yes, you're right, @Ned. That's what I was missing.